# Window Mobile SMS Source Code

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, sms

I need to develop a windows mobile sms application. I am a new mobile software programmer so i need a source code to use it as a template and learn from it. Can any one provide me with a source code ? i don't care about the interface. I just need the functionality.

Comment: What do you mean by "sms application"? Do you want to send, receive or both? Do you want to integrate with the built in app? How/do you want to integrate with the contact list? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not mistaken, when you install de Windows Mobile 6 SDK there are examples included, there is a SMS one but it's in c++.

Answer (score 1):

If you're thinking about a managed code application then you can use the SmsMessage object in the Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook namespace.

Here's an article describing the process:

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/38571